# How to page break after specific Grouped record(Suppose 6) in rdlc?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have a 3 level grouped Table and want to page break when the size of group cross the 6.

I used parent group with sort expression like

```
System.Math.Ceiling((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/6)+1
```

But its giving an error

```
The definition of the report 'D:\WebServicesDemo\VStM\VStM\RdlcReports\ListUser.rdlc' is invalid.
A sort expression for tablix ‘Tablix4’ uses the RowNumber function. RowNumber cannot be used in sort expressions.
```

I only want to break page after 6 record. so how can i achieve this.

My grouping image is

[image: Grouping for page breaking]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Group Properties -> Sorting tab and delete one item in options